# Do Random Forests work with an Ordered Factor as outcome variable?

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

I have an integer target variable with 4 different unique values, which I interpret as an Ordered Factor. Can I feed it to the `randomForest()` function or when using caret to train a random forest, does the `train()` function accept it?

I used the command `as.ordered()` to change the variable type to ordered factor.

Answer (score 0):

This is ordinal logistic regression - you can use the `ordinalForest` package to do this in R.

You can call `ordinalForest` in `caret` using `method='ordinalRF'`